# Simulating the highlight recovery tool from Photoshop

Tags: algorithm, graphics, image-processing

I'm interested in processing a bitmap in Java using the same (or similar) technique as the Highlight recovery tool in Photoshop.  (That would be the Image->Adjustments->Shadow/Highlight tool in CS4.)

I googled around, and found very little outside of discussion about existing tools that do the job.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Just guessing because I don't have Photoshop - only going by the descriptions I find on the web.

The Radius control is probably used in a Gaussian Blur to get the average value around a pixel, to determine its level of highlight or shadow. Shadows will be closer to 0 while highlights will be closer to 255. The exact definition of "close" will be determined by the Tonal Width control. For example, at 100% maybe the shadows go from 0-63 and the highlights go from 192-255.

The Amount corresponds to the amount of brightness change desired - again I don't know the scale, or what equates to 100%. Changing the brightness of the shadows requires multiplying by a constant value - for example to brighten it by 100% would require multiplying by 2. You want to scale this by the shadow value determined above. The highlights work similarly, except working down from 255 instead of up from 0.

Comment: I tried this in Java on BufferedImage and it works well. I ended up setting my shadow upper bounds at 100 and my highlight lower bound at 155, but I primarily edit astrophotos so results will vary. As a side note, it helped to convert RGB to HSL prior to making luminance adjustments, then converting back after the adjustment was made, although I suspect keeping things in RGB space will make things much faster.